# AWK Split Variable

Tags: awk, regular-expression, pattern-matching

I have the following sequence in a file:

```
AA
MUi
MUi-j
MUi-N
ABk
ABk-l
ABk-N
MBk(i)
MBk-l(i)
MBk-l(i-j)
MBk-l(i-N)
MBk-N(i-j)
MBk-N(i-N)
```

I want to split it in small pieces:
The first two chars will always exist, the rest are optional.
i,j,k,l are numbers that can vary from 1 to 191.
N is the character "N".
I want to have the following result:

```
AA
MU i
MU i j
MU i N
AB k
AB k l
AB k N
MB k i
MB k l i
MB k l i j
MB k l i N
MB k N i j
MB k N i N
```

Can this be done with AWK patsplit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via `sed`:

```
sed 's/^../& /;s/[-()]/ /g' datafile.dat
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk:

```
$ gawk -vFPAT='[A-Z]+|[a-z]' 'NF+=0' file
AA
MU i
MU i j
MU i N
AB k
AB k l
AB k N
MB k i
MB k l i
MB k l i j
MB k l i N
MB k N i j
MB k N i N
```

Note that will skip empty lines, since it relies on a non-zero side-effect value of `NF+=0` to trigger the default `print`; if that's undesirable, you can use the slightly more verbose `{NF+=0} 1`.